# Unity can't build to android, Android Dependencies Detected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Whenever I try to make a build of an android application it gives me this issue, I've tried ticking on the Custom Main Gradle Template but that just causes more errors to occur and I have no idea. Unfortunately it's impossible to update or reinstall Android SDK module because maybe it's a problem with that so I don't know what to do

Edit:
I removed Unity Meditation and I got an error with Gradle

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugJavaResource
> aapt2.exe W 11-28 09:16:10 20148 33388 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'.

> Task :launcher:bundleDebugResources

> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug
> 26 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 10 up-to-date
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

[image]

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-build-error-sdk-incompatible-with-the-package-how-do-i-solve.1363974/
Same issue as me, did the same things with the same errors, no resolution

Comment: Are you using Unity Mediation?

Comment: Yes I believe I am, should I remove it?

Comment: You need to use the Editor versions supporting the Medition. Check in this link https://docs.unity.com/mediation/IntroToMediation.html

Answer (score 1):

Update: I got it working magically. If you're having a similar issue then my solution from what I believe I did was remove all Advertising and In-App Purchasing packages (while also reverting back to an older Git build where the newer versions were added and removed it) and then reinstalled. So takeaway is to never update Unity packages without having a Git branch you can revert back to if it fails, and test after updating too